# Using purrr::pmap or purrr:invoke_rows to create functions from data.frame

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

I'm attempting to create functions using rows of a data.frame. I want each function to be associated with a row of the data.frame so would like to store them in a list column of my data.frame.

I've attempted to do this using some `purrr` functions, namely `pmap` and `invoke_rows`.

Example:

```
a <- as.data.frame(list(col1 = c(1,2,3), col2 = c(2,3,4)))

function_factory <- function(col1, col2) {
  function() {
    print(col1)
    runif(1, min = col1, max = col2)
  }
}

my_functions <- a %>% invoke_rows(.f = function_factory, .d = ., .to = "col3")

my_functions$col3[[1]]()
my_functions$col3[[2]]()
my_functions$col3[[3]]()
```

Each function prints 3 (the last row of col1) rather than the value of col1 on the row that generated the function.

I can make this work with Map, but wanted to understand what I am doing wrong with the `purrr` functions. Any ideas?

This is my function using Map:

```
map_to_listcolumn <- function(.d, .f, .labels = TRUE, .to = "out") {

    .d <- as.data.frame(.d)

    new_map <- purrr::lift_dl(Map, f = .f) 

    to_col <- new_map(.d[, names(formals(.f)), drop = FALSE])

    if(.labels == TRUE) {
      .d[.to] <- I(list(to_col))
      return(.d)
    } else {
      return(to_col)
    }

  }
```

Comment: The output should be a list column of functions (this is stated in the opening paragraph). If you remove the function element then you get the results, not a function. `invoke_rows` seems to work as expected if the return type is not a function. It is when returning a function that these problems seem to arise.

Comment: This seems like it could be a lazy evaluation-type issue and along those lines I found [this open github issue](https://github.com/hadley/purrr/issues/191) that might be related.

Comment: The work around in the second comment of the github issue, adding `col1` and `col2` before the function that you want returned, might be what you need.

Comment: You are Right!! It's a lazy evaluation issue. This is covered well in Hadley's book http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html. One solution is to use `force(col1)`, `force(col2)` within the above `function_factory`. adding `col1` and `col2` probably has the same effect - forcing evaluation prior to the creation of the function.